# what is this c++ templated function doing

Tags: c++, templates, angelscript

I'm trying to write a thin wrapper around [AngelScript](http://www.angelcode.com/angelscript/).  I'm having trouble figuring out how to wrap around a particular struct.

Here is the struct definition for the struct I want to wrap, `asSMethodPtr`:

```
template <int N>
struct asSMethodPtr
{
    template<class M>
    static asSFuncPtr Convert(M Mthd)
    {
        // This version of the function should never be executed, nor compiled,
        // as it would mean that the size of the method pointer cannot be determined.

        int ERROR_UnsupportedMethodPtr[N-100];

        asSFuncPtr p;
        return p;
    }
};
```

Here is the definition for `asSFuncPtr`:

```
struct asSFuncPtr
{
    union
    {
        char dummy[25]; // largest known class method pointer
        struct {asFUNCTION_t func; char dummy[25-sizeof(asFUNCTION_t)];} f;
    } ptr;
    asBYTE flag; // 1 = generic, 2 = global func
};
```

Here is the code I've found (taken from the [AngelBinder](https://code.google.com/p/angelbinder/) library) that allows me to 'wrap' it:

```
template<typename R> ClassExporter& method(std::string name, R (T::*func)())
{
    MethodClass mthd(name, Type<R>::toString(), asSMethodPtr< sizeof( void (T::*)() ) >::Convert( AS_METHOD_AMBIGUITY_CAST( R (T::*)()) (func) ));
    this->_methods.push(mthd);
    return *this;
}
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea what this code is doing...

What is `T::*` supposed to do?  A pointer to the class type?

What is `R (T::*func)()`?

Any help appreciated...

Comment: `R (T::*func)()` defines a variable as a function pointer named `func`, which is a member of class `T`, takes no parameters (other than the implicit `this`) and returns `R`

Comment: Does it actually compile? This will compile, as far as I can tell, only if `sizeof( void (T::*)() )` is greater than `100`... Hold on, is that C++ or this scripting language?.. And you don't have `T::*` - if you look closely it's `void (T::*)()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T::*` is a pointer-to-member.  `R (T::*func)()` is a pointer to a member function that returns `R` and takes 0 parameters. For example:

```
struct S
{
    int f()
    {
        return 5;
    }

    int x = 10;
};

int main()
{
    S s;

    int S::* ptr = &S::x;

    std::cout << s.*ptr; // 10

    int (S::*f_ptr)() = &S::f;

    std::cout << (s.*f_ptr)(); // 5
}
```

Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8336763.aspx).

Comment: awesome, makes much more sense now :)  Thanks @0x499602D2